Update state after returning from second page
I have this code
void _setScreen(String identifiers,int id) {
  if (identifiers == _get_Current_Screen_Identifier()) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    if (identifiers == 'page1') {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => const Page1()));
    }
    if (identifiers == 'page2') {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => const Page2()));
    }
  }
}

The first screen to show when I open the application is Page1. In Page2 I can add some kind of value in a table of the DB (sqlite). In Page1, after any kind of operation, I do setState to see if these values are updated/added/delete, but when I returned from Page2 to Page1 the value doesn't update, until I do some operation that calls setState.
Is there a way to do that?
I've tried
void _setScreen(String identifiers,int id) {
  if (identifiers == _get_Current_Screen_Identifier()) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    if (identifiers == 'page1') {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => const Page1()));
    }
    if (identifiers == 'page2') {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => const Page2())).then(
        (value) {
        setState(() {
        });
      });
    }
  }
}

But it still doesn't work.
EDIT
Build method in Page2 return this
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          FutureBuilder<List<double>>(
            future: _databaseService.getFinacialAmount(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 250,
                    child: DonutChart(
                        expenses: snapshot.data![0],
                        entries: snapshot.data![1]),
                  ),
                );

So i need a method to re-build the build method.
Thanks

You can add value in pop() method ... in 2nd screen -Navigator.of(context).pop(value); and get in 1st screen as Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (BuildContext context) => yourscreen( ))).then((value) => () {
print(value);
});

I understand, but in Page2 I don't have any method, that make this kind of operation

Hey dear @MatteoPreda , Welcome to our community. Check my answer and if it fixes your issue please press check ✅ button and upvote it

If you go to Page2 and do some actions, then come back to Page1 and want to update your values you can use the await method
you can do something like this:

IMPORTANT Do NOT forget to add async in your function.

void _setScreen(String identifiers,int id) async{}

Use Below Code:
await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => const Page2()));
setState((){});

Now call setState((){});
and any other action you b
need to apply
For instance:
onTap: () async {
 await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
 builder: (ctx) => const Page2()));                                  
//////Call SetState or any other action...                            
print("do Actions"); }

Let me know if your problem is solved or not.
Happy Coding :)

Yes, You can
Page 1
 Future<void> pushToSettingScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    //
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const yourScreenName(),
      ),
    );

    if (!mounted) return;
    //
    if (result == 'reloadMe') {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(result);
      }

        setState(() {
         screenLoader = true;
        }); // your whole screen reload automatically
    }
  }

In Page 2

Use Navigator.pop(context,'reloadMe') instead of Navigator.pop(context)

